# where do I install custom completions for a python command line script on OSX

Tags: macos, shell, homebrew, pkg-config, bash-completion

In the bash-completions read me it states:

> Q. I author/maintain package X and would like to maintain my own
>   completion code for this package. Where should I put it to be sure
>   that interactive bash shells will find it and source it?
>
> Install it in one of the directories pointed to by
>   bash-completion's pkgconfig file variables.  There are two
>   alternatives: the recommended one is 'completionsdir' (get it with
>   "pkg-config --variable=completionsdir bash-completion") from which
>   completions are loaded on demand based on invoked commands' names,
>   so be sure to name your completion file accordingly, and to include
>   for example symbolic links in case the file provides completions
>   for more than one command.  The other one which is present for
>   backwards compatibility reasons is 'compatdir' (get it with
>   "pkg-config --variable=compatdir bash-completion") from which files
>   are loaded when bash_completion is loaded.

However, on OS X after installing bash-comletion via homebrew this doesn't work:

```
pkg-config --variable=completionsdir bash-completion

Package bash-completion was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `bash-completion.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'bash-completion' found
```

How/where would I install custom completions for a command line script I've written and will install via pip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `echo $BASH_COMPLETION` in the terminal to get where the bash completion are installed

if you used homebrew it's most likely in `/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/`